# Drag files or Folder upon build .exe file not launching the App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, path, electron

In my reactjs based electron desktop application, Once I am dragging any file(or Folder) which is outside the current folder path, Upon the generated build .exe file, App is not launching. After these steps, the app stops launching even with a double click.

But if I drag any file from the same directory app is launching correctly.

After debugging I found instead of launching the app is going into the background process in Taskmanager in the window system. Hence not able to see the app window.

So is there any electron event that gets triggered whenever we drop any file over the build executable file?

Even tried with open-file and open-link, it does not do the purpose.
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-open-file-macos

Thanks in advance. Looking for a great response. Any Suggestings or help would be appreciated.

Comment: As per more investigation I found that 
window.once('ready-to-show', () => {}); is not getting triggered. When drag a file from outside current file exprorer path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was present in the file path. I was using a relative path(ex **./build/demo.txt**) to read/write files or folders.
Once I used an absolute(**root** + **./build/demo.txt**) path instead app is working normally.